# generate classes from Scss / Sass nested map

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

How does one generate a list of classes for each key that has a single value inside a Scss/Sass map?

For example, from this Scss map (disregard nested naming conventions, this will be used for many maps of varying purposes):

(See Codepen: http://codepen.io/harlanlewis/pen/emWVrr (thanks cimmanon!))

```
$palette: (
  brown: hsl(33,35,50),
  blue: hsl(207,80,50),

  green: (
    0: hsl(157,65,65),
    1: hsl(157,50,50),
    alt: (
      0: hsl(125,65,65),
    ),
  ),

  red: (
    0: hsl(0,60,50),
    alt: (
      0: hsl(0,100,50),
    ),
  ),

  yellow: (
    0: hsl(50,100,60),
    1: hsl(50,100,100),
  ),
};
```

-

```
@mixin map-to-class($map, $selector: '', $property: '') {
    $selector: if($selector == '' and &, &, $selector);

    @each $key, $value in $map {
        @if type-of($value) == map {
            $selector: selector-append($selector, #{$key});
            @include map-to-class($value, $selector, $property) {
                @content;
            }
        } @else {
          @at-root #{$selector}#{$key} {
                #{$property}: $value;
            };
        };
    };
};
@include map-to-class($palette, '.u-fg__', 'color')
```

...desired classes to generate:

```
.u-fg__brown { color: hsl(33,35,50) }
.u-fg__blue { color: hsl(207,80,50) }

.u-fg__green0 { color: hsl(157,65,65) }
.u-fg__green1 { color: hsl(157,50,50) }
.u-fg__greenalt0 { color: hsl(125,65,65) }

.u-fg__red0 { color: hsl(0,60,50) }
.u-fg__redalt0 { color: hsl(0,100,50) }

.u-fg__yellow0 { color: hsl(50,100,60) }
.u-fg__yellow1 { color: hsl(50,100,80) }
```

**The actual (incorrect) generated classes are:** (note `greenredyellow` instead of just `yellow`)

```
... (brown, blue, and green are fine) ...
.u-fg__green0 { color: hsl(157,65,65) }
.u-fg__green1 { color: hsl(157,50,50) }
.u-fg__greenalt0 { color: hsl(125,65,65) }

.u-fg__greenred0 { color: hsl(0,60,50) }
.u-fg__greenredalt0 { color: hsl(0,100,50) }

.u-fg__greenredyellow0 { color: hsl(50,100,60) }
.u-fg__greenredyellow1 { color: hsl(50,100,80) }
```

Comment: So is there a question here?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried working from the map-get-deep function, but it's messy - hoping someone can recommend an alternate approach. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a recursive mixin.  Walk through the mapping.  If the value is a mapping, call itself otherwise print out the property/value.

```
$palette: (
  'brown': hsl( 33,  35,  50),
  'blue': hsl(207, 80,  50),

  'green': (
    0: hsl(157, 65, 65),
    1: hsl(157, 50, 50),
    alt: (
      0: hsl(125, 65, 65),
    ),
  ),

  'red': (
    0: hsl(0, 60, 50),
    alt: (
      0: hsl(0, 100, 50),
    ),
  ),

  'yellow': (
    0: hsl(50, 100, 60),
    2: hsl(50, 100, 100),
  ),
);


@mixin map-to-class($map, $property, $sel, $divider: '') {
    $sel: if($sel == '' and &, &, $sel);
    @debug $sel;

    #{$sel} {
        @each $k, $v in $map {
            @at-root #{$sel}#{$divider}#{$k} {
                @if type-of($v) == map {
                    @include map-to-class($v, $property, '', $divider) {
                        @content;
                    }
                } @else {
                    #{$property}: $v;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@include map-to-class($palette, color, '.u-fg__', '');
```

Output:

```
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__brown {
  color: #ac8453;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__blue {
  color: #198ae6;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__green0 {
  color: #6ce0b3;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__green1 {
  color: #40bf8e;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__greenalt0 {
  color: #6ce075;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__red0 {
  color: #cc3333;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__redalt0 {
  color: red;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__yellow0 {
  color: #ffdd33;
}
/* line 33, ../sass/test.scss */
.u-fg__yellow2 {
  color: white;
}
```

Note that I quoted your mapping key names.  Sass will convert those to their hex code equivalents under certain compression types.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response! Upvoted. I'll be working more with it later today.

Comment: I've largely fit this to my purposes, however there is an issue with multiple nested lists in which every preceding sibling nested list key is prepended to the generated class name. Struggled with it quite a bit was unable to resolve. View here: http://codepen.io/harlanlewis/pen/emWVrr

Comment: Can you show me what the generated CSS should look like?

Comment: Not quite there - the above results in classes like: `.u-fg__green .u-fg__greenalt .u-fg__green .u-fg__greenalt0 { color: #6ce075; }`, as seen here: http://codepen.io/harlanlewis/pen/yyXyrJ. Continuing to work on it.

Comment: Whoops, I made a minor change and thought it was giving the same results.  Should work now.

Comment: Awesome! This is the first I've seen@at-root outside the relatively straightforward keyframe animations, I'm sure I'll find more uses for it as I explore Sass maps. Huge thank you!